# intersection of convex regions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Consider $n$ vectors in $R^n$ given by $a_1=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and $a_2=(-1,1,\ldots,1)$, $a_{3}=(-1,-1,1,\ldots,1)$,..., $a_n=(-1,-1,\ldots,-1,1).$ Suppose we are given $2n$ positive numbers $\lambda_i$, $1\leq i\leq 2n.$ For $1\leq i\leq n$ we define $P_i=\{x:~ \langle x,a_i\rangle\leq \lambda_i\}$, and for $n+1\leq i\leq 2n$, we define $P_i=\{x:~ \langle x,-a_{i-n}\rangle\leq \lambda_i\}.$ Is the intersection of $P_i,$ $\cap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i$, a compact region?

Comment: I meant compact.

Comment: Is the region closed and bounded?  You know it's closed, so you have to check that it's bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint take $ x \in \cap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i $ looking at first component of $x$ i.e, $x_1 $ you can show that this $x_1 \in R$ running over a bounded set as $x$ running a over $\cap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i$! To show this , let assume WLOG $x_1 \rightarrow -\infty$, by extracting suitable subsequence of $x \in \cap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i$. since $x \in P_2 \cap P_n$ we have $\langle a_2, x \rangle \leq \lambda_2$
and $\langle - a_1 , x \rangle\leq \lambda_{n+1} $ therefore
$$  -2 x_1 =\langle a_2-a_1 , x \rangle \leq \lambda_1 + \lambda_{n+1} $$
Which is a contradiction, similar idea works for other components of $x$ (some of them requires more P_i s).

Comment: I like this, a solid argument should come out of it, thanks.

Comment: Ok, two sets should enough $a_{i}-a_{i+1}=2e_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$ and $a_1+a_{n}=2e_n$ and $x\in P_{i}\cap P_{i+1+n}$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$ or $x\in P_1\cap P_n$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: None of the $P_i$ Are compact. Neither are the $P_i \cap P_{i+n}, i=1,\dots,n,$ but they are bounded in the direction of $a_i$ and are essentially closed tubular neighborhoods of $\{a_i\}^\perp$. What is the intersection of these orthogonal complements? Just $\vec{0}$, so we should expect $\bigcap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i$ to be a compact neighborhood of $\vec{0}$.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: I can edit this to make it more clear, but it may help to think about what these sets look like.

Comment: $P_i$ is parallel to $P_{i+n}$ so?

Comment: I don't think parallel is accurate, but they are mirror images of each other.

Comment: $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_{i+n}.$

Comment: True, but does that make much difference? It's merely a distortion. You could assume without loss of generality that all the $\lambda_i$ are equal to the largest one.

Comment: I'm not sure why I thought those pairwise intersections were "tapered", but I've fixed it. The basic idea was still correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. Define 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}a_1&\cdots&a_n\end{pmatrix}^T,\Lambda_1 = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&\cdots&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}^T, \Lambda_2 = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{n+1}&\cdots&\lambda_{2n}\end{pmatrix}^T,$$
$$ \cal{C} = \{y\in\mathbb{R}^n: -\Lambda_2\leq y\leq\Lambda_1 \ \ (\mathrm{entrywise})\}.$$
Clearly $\cal{C}$ is compact and $A$ is nonsingular, so $\bigcap_{i=1}^{2n}P_i = A^{-1}\cal{C}$ is compact.